# Preventing duplicate scanner user input

Tags: java, validation, input

This program I am writing is giving me fits. What I am trying to do is prevent a user from entering the same integer twice. The program takes 4 int inputs and compares them to an array of 4 random int's, searching for a match. Here is what I have thus far in my attempts to prevent multiple inputs.

```
for (int z = 0; z<4; z++){
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 0-9. No duplicates please!");
            temp[z] = inputDevice.nextInt();

            for(int why = 0; why<temp.length; why++){
                if(Arrays.asList(temp).contains(temp[z])){
                    System.out.println("Duplicate found! Please enter a non-repeating digit");
                    temp[z]=0;
                    z--;
                }
            }


            }
```

The inputs are coming into the temp array just fine. And are being passed on to the other methods  in the program, and that is working. I am guessing the issue is with my conditional statement - if(Arrays.asList(temp).contains(temp[z]))

Is there a better way to test to see if an array already contains a value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since you are converting the array to a list, might as well use an `ArrayList`

2) Store your input in a variable and test if it is contained within the list already

```
List<Integer> my_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int z = 0; z<4; z++){
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 0-9. No duplicates please!");
    int input = inputDevice.nextInt();
    if(my_list.contains(input)){
        System.out.println("Duplicate found! Please enter a non-repeating digit");
        z--;
    }
    else{
        my_list.add(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! I just have to figure out how to copy this array List to my other array that does my calculations for me. Thanks C.B. Wish I could give you credit for the answer but I dont have enough rep to do so yet. But I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you check if temp contains z, it already contains z. Put the input in a temporary variable before you check it and only add it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `why` from your loop.

However if possible I would change `temp` to an `ArrayList` implementation. The problem with `toList` method. It's using the `int[]` array as a single object rather than treating it as an array of `int` objects. To do the latter you must use `Integer`s.

Comment: For some reason that if statement is not detecting duplicates.